# How to clear an input element with modern browser (that has shadowDOM inner-editor)?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

```
  document.getElementById('taginput').addEventListener('paste',function(e){
    var clipboardData, pastedData, inputdata, tempData, tempTags = [], currentTags = [], out = '';
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    inpudata = document.getElementById('taginput').value + pastedData;
    tempData = pastedData.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length - 1; i++) {
      if(tempTags.indexOf(tempData[i].trim()) === -1) tempTags.push(tempData[i].trim());
    }
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('dynamictags')[0].children).forEach(function(data){
      currentTags.push(data.innerText);
    });
    tempTags.forEach(function(data){
      if (currentTags.indexOf(data) === -1) out += '<res>' + data + '</res>';
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName('dynamictags')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('dynamictags')[0].innerHTML + out;
    this.value = '';
    this.value = tempData[tempData.length - 1].trim();
  }, false);
```

This is my current code, the problem with this implementation is that `this.value = ''` doesn't reset the input field, and `this.value = tempData[tempData.length - 1].trim();
      }, false);` would simple add new text before the userinput in the input field.

For example, if I paste `apple, apple , orange, banana` into the field, it will remain and add banana and become `banana apple, apple , orange, banana`.

Comment: this.value == '';  => Note that == is the comparation operator, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shadow-DOM browsers you need this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('taginput').value = tempData[tempData.length - 1].trim();
},0);
```